# get tag name from xsi:type using xmpullparser

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, xmlpullparser, android-xmlpullparser

I have following XML file:

```
<refObjects xsi:type="xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<id>123</id>
<tagfoo>Name 1</tagfoo>
</refObjects>
<refObjects xsi:type="xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>456</id>
    <tagfoo>Name 2</tagfoo>
</refObjects>
<refObjects xsi:type="xml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <id>789</id>
    <tagfoo>Name 3</tagfoo>
</refObjects>
```

I want to get values from "id" and "tagfoo". In my eventtype START_TAG I can read name of tag, type, value, etc, but can't get text. In my event type TEXT I cannot read this tag information. How would I get those values?

Comment: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/android-simple-xmlpullparser-tutorial/ . It may help!

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung It does not help as latest Android API's do now allow coding in that fashion. Now it has to be done using AsyncTask and int cannot be done this way.